# getElementsByTagName ignoring relative url

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

hi i am using below code to extract few images whose size is bigger than 30 kb and it works just fine if the src in image tag is absoulte url but it fails if the src tag in img url is relative url as i am checking the size of the image i think it is unable to check relative url file. how i can make it check the size of relative as well as absolute url

```
     $websitelink='http://www.xyziiiii.com/im-giving-you-3-guesses-where-model-isabela-soncini-is-from';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $websitelink);    
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 $result = curl_exec($ch);

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
 $doc->loadHTML($result); // loads your html
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
foreach ($tags as $tag) { 
 $data = get_headers($tag->getAttribute('src'),1); 
  if((intval($data["Content-Length"])/1024)>=30){ 
   $op7=''.$tag->getAttribute('src').'';
   echo  $op7;
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the relative URL to the end of your original URL. It should be resolved correctly.

Comment: @user3026718: `http://example.com/path/to/file.php/../../images/file.jpg` should resolve correctly to `http://example.com/path/images/file.jpg`.

Comment: it will notr work always sometimes if relative url is in thr form of .../path/to/relative it will fail

Comment: @user3026718: Try it, and see. Also `.../path/to/relative` is not a valid relative URL. Read the answer again.

Comment: i have already tried this $var = parse_url($websitelink);
$tithref=$var['scheme'] . '://' . $var['host'];
   and the above path is correct .if you are referring three directory up you have to mention three times dot

Comment: @user3026718: No, three directories up is `../../../`.

Comment: i have already tried for parsing the host url which can be prefixed but its not working for this url. can u please check once?  http://www.joblo.com/hollywood-celebrities/gossip/im-giving-you-3-guesses-where-model-isabela-soncini-is-from